# Two axis on a BarChart

Tags: plotting

I want to create a `BarChart` with two different y-axis, one on the left and another one on the right. For that, I did two different `BarChart` I tried to overlay them

```
a= {{0.355556, 0.555556, 0}, {23.3115, 19.7992, 0}, {0.395476, 0.482037, 0}, {3.34386, 2.48343, 0}, {0.0400976, 0.0698065, 0}, {0.911938, 0.840873, 0}, {0.182678, 0.132822, 0}, {0.184268, 0.379897, 0}, {26.9781, 35.3149, 0}, {0.302316, 0.337643, 0}, {2.78961, 2.52604, 0}}

b={{0, 0, 0.36}, {0, 0, -0.177399}, {0, 0, 0.179574}, {0, 0, -0.346465}, {0, 0, 0.425589}, {0, 0, -0.0845136}, {0, 0, -0.375361}, {0, 0, 0.514952}, {0, 0, 0.23607}, {0, 0, 0.104629}, {0, 0, -0.10434}}

Plot1 = BarChart[a, BarSpacing -> {0, 1}, BaseStyle -> $TextStyle, ImageMargins -> 5, ImageSize -> 500, ChartStyle -> {Darker[Red], Orange}, PlotRange -> {Automatic, {-1, 35}}, Frame -> Left, FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {None, Automatic}}, Background -> None]

Plot2 = BarChart[b, BarSpacing -> {0, 1}, Frame -> Right, FrameStyle -> Darker[Blue], ChartStyle -> {Darker[Blue]}, FrameTicks -> All, PlotRange -> {Automatic, {-0.5, 2.5}}, BaseStyle -> $TextStyle, ImageMargins -> 5, ImageSize -> 500]
Overlay[{Plot1, Plot2}, Alignment -> Bottom, BaselinePosition -> Bottom]
```

However, I am not able to properly align them. How can I align them at `y = 0`?

Answer (score 4):

### Edit 2 : Improved Version

Firstly I'm renaming your data set `b` as `b1`.

Create a new data `c` such that

```
c = a + (10*b1);
```

I'm scaling the data set `b1` according to the axis you wanted.

Create a barchart for `c`

```
 Plot3 = BarChart[c, BarSpacing -> {0, 1}, Frame -> Left, 
  FrameTicks -> All, BarOrigin -> Bottom, 
  ChartStyle -> {Darker[Red], Orange, Darker[Blue]}, 
  PlotRange -> {Automatic, {0, 35}}, BaseStyle -> $TextStyle, 
  ImageMargins -> 5, ImageSize -> 500];
```

Create the right axis separately

```
axis = BarChart[{}, FrameTicks -> All, Frame -> Right, 
    Axes -> {False, False}, ImageSize -> 500, 
   PlotRange -> {{0, 0}, {-0.5, 2.5}}, FrameStyle -> Darker[Blue]]
```

Now we can Overlay `Plot3` and `axes` as before:

```
p1 = Overlay[{Plot3, 
Graphics[{}, AspectRatio -> (h + b + t)/(w + l + r), 
ImageSize -> {w + l + r, h + b + t}, ImagePadding -> 10, 
Epilog -> {Dynamic[Locator[Dynamic[pt], axis]]}]}, All, 2]
```

Finally we get after

```
 p2 = p1 /. Locator[x_, y_] :> Inset[y, x] /. Dynamic :> Identity
```

[image]

---

### Edit 1

First run the below for initializing certain parameters;

```
 {w, h} = {500, 300};
 pt = Scaled[{0.5, 0.5}];
 {{l, r}, {b, t}} = {{80, 40}, {60, 10}};
```

Now you generate your two barchart named `Plot1` and `Plot2`.
Then we will overlay the second on the first dynamically so that you can move 
the second plot freely on top of the first one.

```
  p1 = Overlay[{Plot1, 
  Graphics[{}, AspectRatio -> (h + b + t)/(w + l + r), 
 ImageSize -> {w + l + r, h + b + t}, ImagePadding -> 10,
 Epilog -> {Dynamic[Locator[Dynamic[pt], Plot2]]}]}, All, 2]
```

After you have placed the second plot where you want it to be, you can then make the shift permanent as follows:

```
 p2 = p1 /. Locator[x_, y_] :> Inset[y, x] /. Dynamic :> Identity
```

Is this the final result you wanted:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. There is, however, one problem. At the moment, the blue bar is over the red and orange bars and I want the to have the blue bar just side with the red and orange bars {red,orange,blue}, without barspacings, or at least with the same barspacing. Do you know how to have the x-axis of both plots exactly the same size?

Comment: Check the edited answer